# Enumerating FTPFile from FTP using ZipFile

Tags: java, apache, ftp, apache-commons-net

My usual approach without an FTP to read ZipFiles was the following:

```
private void getLogFromZip(File logZip){
  ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(logZip);
  Enumeration<?> entries = zf.entries();
  while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry ze = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
  //do something with entry    
}
```

Now that I have a connection to an FTP server, retrieving an FTPFile and using it makes things difficult:

```
private void getLogFromZip(FTPFile logZip){
  ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(logZip.getName()); //here's the problem
  Enumeration<?> entries = zf.entries();
  while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry ze = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
  //do something with entry    
}
```

Directly in line 1 I am getting this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: logger_150510_092333.zip (System cannot find the file? specified)
```

What is a workaround for that? How can I specify a path so that it knows where to look for the zip?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to get the file from the FTP server first, before you can access it. The `FTPFile` instance appears to be only a link to the actual file.

Have a look here for an example: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/03/apache-commons-ftpclient-java-example_16.html

Comment: Is there no way to not download the files from the FTP but work in a somewhat (virtual) space?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to get the file locally (by downloading it) to enumerate its content. You could probably download only the header of the file by requesting say first couple of kBs of the file but that's pretty much it.